# Can't read a folder Java

Tags: java, url, javafx, uri

So I'm trying to make an applet in JavaFX.
I have a folder in my src called "sprites".
In that folder there are about 700 images, but whenever I try to initialize an ImageView it gives me a NullPointerException.

```
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("src\\sprites\\image.png"));
```

The above code doesn't work, and when I give it an absolute filepath:

```
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("C:\\User\\...\\src\\sprites\\image.png"));
```

It doesn't work either.

However, if I move all 700 images to the root of my src folder, it works perfectly fine:

```
 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("image.png"));
```

Is there a way around this for organizational purposes?
I don't want to keep hundreds of files in my src folder, I'd rather have them in different folders to make things neater

Answer (score 0):

If i remember...

Java applet cannot access user disk for security purpose.
If you want to do this, you can, but you need to sign your applet with a certificate.

You can provide an auto-signed certificate. This will be enough for you to test your applet, but users should accept it if they want to work with your app ;)

Comment: first line of question " I'm trying to make an applet"...